# Tags doesn't created with django-taggit

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, django-taggit

I using django-taggit and I have a problem with creation tags field with next code:

```
tags = TaggableManager()
```

All other fields from model are created. But tags don't :( 
I tried with Django1.7.1 and 1.7.2, also with db's sqLite and MySql.

In migrations is created

```
('tags', taggit.managers.TaggableManager(to='taggit.Tag', through='taggit.TaggedItem', help_text='A comma-separated list of tags.', verbose_name='Tags'))
```

but why it doesnt apply... I don't know. Somebody has a idea?

Comment: Please, show code where you save your objects. Maybe you use commit=False? In that case you should call save_m2m after save().

Comment: I didn't save objects. I made migration and after go to DB manager and see how table is created. Field with tags not creating in table.

Comment: Hmmm, but you have option through='taggit.TaggedItem'. It means there is separate table for many-to-many relations between Tags and your Model.

Comment: Wow, I'm filing like a noob :) Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option `through='taggit.TaggedItem'` means that there is separate table for many-to-many relations.